# Raid-10 mdadm - How to Manually Configure Mirrored Drive Order?

Tags: raid, software-raid, mdadm, raid10

How do I configure a new `mdadm` software RAID-10 to use a specific order for its drive mirroring?

Say I have 4 hard drives: **A**, **B**, **C**, and **D**.

For my own reliability and performance reasons, I want drive **A** to be a mirror of drive **C**, and drive **B** to be a mirror of drive **D**.  Then each mirror striped, like this

```
 |----- RAID-0 ----- |
  RAID-1      RAID-1
|---------| |---------|
| drive A | | drive B |
| drive C | | drive D |
|---------| |---------|
```

I don't see a way to configure this. Not sure about the drive order this command produces:

`mdadm --create /dev/md0 --level=10 --raid-devices=4 /dev/sd[a-d]1`

Is there a way to manually order the drives in a `mdadm` array?

If not, is there a way to check the order after the array is created so I could physically move the drives into the configuration I want?  (I think I can create the array members using `/dev/disk/by-id/ata*` so I can physically move them without worrying about `/dev/sd*` re-ordering.)

Bonus question. I also will want a hot spare, drive **E**, to be available to either mirror set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think I figured out my own answer.  Set up two RAID-1s first, then RAID-0 them together.

Created two RAID-1 volumes

```
sudo mdadm --create /dev/md/md2a --level=1 --raid-devices=2 /dev/disk/by-id/ata-WDC_serial_number_of_drive_A-part1 /dev/disk/by-id/ata-WDC_serial_number_of_drive_C-part1
sudo mdadm --create /dev/md/md2b --level=1 --raid-devices=2 /dev/disk/by-id/ata-WDC_serial_number_of_drive_B-part1 /dev/disk/by-id/ata-WDC_serial_number_of_drive_D-part1
```

(I used drive ID's instead of `/dev/sda,/dev/sdb,...` to ensure an exact match of the drive I want)

Then, created RAID-0 with the two RAID-1 arrays

```
sudo mdadm --create /dev/md/md2 --level=0 --raid-devices=2 /dev/md/md2a /dev/md/md2b
```

I will update this with results in a couple days, after the arrays sync and after I add a hot-spare drive, and I have time to test.

Comment: Why are you not just creating it with `--level=10` and specifying your four devices? This smells like needless complexity that will come back to bite you later. Probably as soon as you reboot.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Works fine after reboot. Wanted this setup for my own reliability & performance reasons. Drives **A** and **B** are in one external enclosure, and drives **C** and **D** are in another (each have separate power supplies & fans). If one enclosure dies, I want the RAID-10 to stay online. What I did not want was `--level=10` picking its own setup where mirrored drives would be within the same enclosure.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a better option, using RAID10 directly.

First create a RAID10 with 2 missing drives, these will be the only drives to hold the raid data without copies (degraded). Here you use both drive from the same external enclosure, for example **A** and **B**. Then you add the other 2 drives from the other enclosure so the backup of **A+B** is always **C+D**.

```
mdadm --create /dev/md0 --level=10 --raid-devices=4 /dev/sd[a-b]1 missing missing

mdadm --add /dev/md0 /dev/sd[c-d]1
mdadm --add /dev/md0 /dev/sde1
```

You won't know if **A** is a copy of **C** or **D** until you do it, but you still meet the initiaL criteria to separate one (1) full data set per each enclosure.

I added the spare last, since I assume it resides in a third location, or that the location is unknown. Like this we guarantee both enclosures have each one (1) set of data.

Comment: Great idea! Thanks.  Creating the RAID-10 with 2 only (drives A and B) guarantees the first two will be striped, then adding more drives (C and D) makes that stripe as mirrors of the first two, ensuring a full copy exists on each SATA bus. Genius!